# Streaming on apache kafka topic has no output

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I was following the tutorial of the apache Kafka website [link](https://kafka.apache.org/26/documentation/streams/tutorial).

The input topic is processed as stream and middle topics also generated but the final output topic is empty.

Below is the topology output:

```
Topologies:
Sub-topology: 0
Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000 (topics: [input])
  --> KSTREAM-FLATMAPVALUES-0000000001
Processor: KSTREAM-FLATMAPVALUES-0000000001 (stores: [])
  --> KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000002
  <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000
Processor: KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000002 (stores: [])
  --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000006
  <-- KSTREAM-FLATMAPVALUES-0000000001
Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000006 (stores: [])
  --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000005
  <-- KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000002
Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000005 (topic: KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000003-repartition)
  <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000006

Sub-topology: 1
Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000007 (topics: [KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000003-repartition])
  --> KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000004
Processor: KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000004 (stores: [KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000003])
  --> KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000008
  <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000007
Processor: KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000008 (stores: [])
  --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000009
  <-- KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000004
Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000009 (topic: streams-wordcount-output)
  <-- KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000008
```

and the code:

```
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(10);

    new Thread(() -> {
        while(latch.getCount() > 0){
            latch.countDown();
            kafkaTopicService.sendMessage("This is a line with 7 words" );
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }).start();
    final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
    final Serde<Long> longSerde = Serdes.Long();

    final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    KStream<String, String> textLines = builder.stream(
            KafkaTopicService.TOPIC_NAME,
            Consumed.with(stringSerde, stringSerde)
    );

    KTable<String, Long> wordCounts = textLines
            // Split each text line, by whitespace, into words.
            .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.toLowerCase().split("\\W+")))

            // Group the text words as message keys
            .groupBy((key, value) -> value)

            // Count the occurrences of each word (message key).
            .count();

    wordCounts.toStream().to("streams-wordcount-output", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));


    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "streams");
    props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
    props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());

    final Topology topology = builder.build();
    System.out.println(topology.describe());
    final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);


    try {
        streams.start();
        latch.await();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
    }
```

Comment: How did you check if the processing is done and the output of the topic? If using console-consumer, ensure that you give --from-beginning flag, just in case if missed.

Comment: Try sending more messages in the above loop and see the result, just

Comment: I have used kafkatool to check the topic's data. the two middle topics are generated on Kafka. But the output topic is not generated at all !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, setting commit interval to 0 would send any change log data immediately to output topic:

```
    props.setProperty(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, String.valueOf(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Groupby works with windowing which is by default 1 day. So, to restream on another topic, the window needs to be closed.  Therefore, closing the window is the solution or setting a low window size that would be closed in running the application.

I have solved the problem by closing the stream.

```
streams.close();
```